# DotSpatial Versions on GitHub

Tags: dotspatial, github, version-control

Trying to understand how version releases work on GitHub. In particular the DotSpatial library https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial.

If I download the master branch and compile it, the results are the DLLs are all at version 2.0.0.0.

However if I just want the compiled DLLs that are ready for use I can click on the link https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/mogikanin/dotspatial/artifacts/Source/bin/Release.zip?branch=master
This contains the DLLs with version 2.0.0.402.

How do the versions work on GitHub?

Comment: The last number is often the build number. If it is not built, it is ok to have it set to 0. Note that it has nothing to do with Github but with the development environment (manual setting, increasing number, number derived from the current date-time etc)

Comment: So who and how does appveyor control the build number? In the code itself I don't see the Assembly information set, so it must be done through a config file of some sort.There are about 94 DLLs as a result of the compilation.

Comment: I think its the file AssemblyInfoShared.cs. It has [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0")] [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0")]. Seems to me If I changed it to 2.0.0.* I would then get a dynamic build.

Comment: yes, but not necessarily. There are some tools/plugins to set any part of the version number "on the fly" without relying on the star notation

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying the file AssemblyInfoShared.cs to a version number that was one digit above the current release.